# Which data structure will you use to storing the pointers to the adjacency linked list for a very big graph?

Tags: hash, graph

Suppose you want to implement a graph which can have million number of nodes.But the nodes count will increase from 0 to million.Its uncertain whether it will reach the million mark or not.It may cross it to multi-million nodes also.

I know adjacency list is what is used for this.But a typical adjacency list has a data structure maintaining pointers to the linked lists.

What data structure then should be used to store the pointers to the adjacency list ?

For example take Facebook for that matter.It has millions of users. Suppose each user represents a node. Now all users are represented as nodes of a very big single graph and you want to do operations on it how will you store it ?

Comment: Discard whatever material you read that told you "hashing generally has a very big array", it is totally false. Also, you are mixing a typical graph structure with hash structures. Rethink about your problem and rewrite the question.

Comment: @mmgp: done answer it now please.

Comment: You are still confused :/ Adjacency list is a way to define which vertices are adjacent to a given vertex. If your graph is dense, there is no reason to use adjacency list. It is also not the problem you are describing, i.e., how to properly store a large graph. There are several questions here in SO about that, there are also many texts about that. Your question is too wide open; research and re-ask.

Comment: @mmgp that i know. Density of graph is not a problem.What if the number of nodes are way too much to store using adjacency list and matrix too.

Comment: what the hell is wrong with the question ? If you dont know the answer stop voting it down.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you know the basics behind them, it shouldn't be too hard.

Generally you create an array called "buckets" that contain the key and value, with an optional pointer to create a linked list.

When you access the hash table with a key, you process the key with a custom hash function which will return an integer. You then take the modulus of the result and that is the location of your array index or "bucket". Then you check the unhashed key with the stored key, and if it matches, then you found the right place.

Otherwise, you've had a "collision" and must crawl through the linked list and compare keys until you match. (note some implementations use a binary tree instead of linked list for collisions).

Check out this fast hash table implementation:

http://attractivechaos.awardspace.com/khash.h.html